# Any Settings for the update the android app

Tags: android

I have upload a application few days back, Now I want to update the application. Is there any settings I need to set in the application, users which have application on their device, once i upload the updated version then how they will receive the "Update Available".

Please help me. I never did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your Application you have to change the AndroidManifest.xml file
and change the code

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

Then you have to upload it in the Google play as you already done for the first time and Google play will automatically intimate the users that an update is available for the application.

Comment: You mean that Google Play will automatically intimate the users when an update is available for the application. But after how many hours google play do this

Comment: @Williams no untill unless they have not set this on play to automaticaly update if they set manual then they will have to check for update

Comment: @Williams If people have checked the auto update the app will automatically be updated if not Google Play will notify them that the app has an update and they can update seeing it manually. And all this will be available in certain time period for different peoples depending on the country and other criteria max time taken will be around 14 hours

Answer (score 1):

take a look through this Android doc http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 1):

If you uploaded a newer version to play store then all your users who have manually set the application to autoupdate allowed mode will receive update but who doesn't set so will have to check and update the application manually

> If you want at programmers end then you shall check it using
>   web-service or using HTTP connection for newer version of application
>
> and then automatically download and prompt user to install this newer
>   version coz you can't install without user's action

[image: Set Auto Update for this app][image: Set Yes to allow updates][image: In settings you can set to get notified]

Assumes You must be changing version in Application Manifest file

if don't know how to set Version follow [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Comment: Even if the app has not be set as auto-update, Play store notifies user every now and then about the installed apps update being available.

Comment: "If you uploaded a newer version to play store then all your users who have manually set the application to autoupdate allowed mode will receive update but who doesn't set so will have to check and update the application manually" Please let me know where to set autoupdate allowed mode

Comment: if you set to get notified or open play store's menu my apps

Comment: Its on user end and only user is responsible to do so these are the settings of playstore